# You don't have permission to access /wordpress/ on this server

Tags: apache-http-server

I have a server running Debian, with an installation of Apache 2.2.16, with PHP/MySQL, and now also an instance of Wordpress. I am playing around with user/group rights on Debian, and I can't make it work the way I want it to.

I believe Apache is using (only) the `www-data` user. The following setup works

```
/var/www# chown -R www-data:nogroup wordpress
/var/www# chmod -R 700 wordpress
/var/www# ls -l | grep wordpress
drwx------ 5 www-data nogroup  4096 Nov  1 09:30 wordpress
```

The following doesn't work.

```
/var/www# groupadd wordpress
/var/www# usermod -a -G wordpress www-data
/var/www# groups www-data
www-data : www-data wordpress
/var/www# chown -R nobody:wordpress wordpress
/var/www# chmod -R 770 wordpress
/var/www# ls -l | grep wordpress
drwxrwx--- 5 nobody wordpress  4096 Nov  1 09:30 wordpress
```

With the above settings, when I try to access the page in my browser, I get:

```
You don't have permission to access /wordpress/ on this server.
```

Here is my understanding: The folders are owned by the group `wordpress`, and the folders have all rights (read, write, execcute) given to the owning group, `wordpress`. Apache user `www-data` is a member of the group `wordpress`, so it should have all rights to the folders.

What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to restart the web server:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Otherwise the group changes won't have any effect. To quickly test to which groups your Apache belongs to you may create a PHP script like:

```
<?php
echo exec('id');
?>
```

Store it in e.g. `/var/www/test.php` and have a look at `http://localhost/test.php`.
If you see the group `wordpress` your setup should be working and you should also be able to access your wordpress blog.

Comment: Restarting Apache fixed it :)